# VW Polo shuddering question

Tags: engine, vw, shaking, polo

I have recently bought a 2007 1.4 VW Polo. I am still adjusting to driving the car and one thing I have managed quite a few times is going uphill in too higher gear or shifting up too soon (my previous car had a bigger engine). However when I do this in the polo I have noticed it shudders - I assumed this was normal as when I shifted down a gear it would stop shuddering and I could shift up once I picked up some more speed.

What worries me is sometimes when I do this the check engine light flashed for maybe 3 seconds until I shift down and then it goes out. After it does this I always check for error codes using my ODB scanner but no errors are every found... Is this maybe just normal behaviour for the polo because it gets close to stalling? The car runs fine otherwise and the CEL never comes on at any other time.

Comment: What you suggest makes sense to me.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked your oil levels? If you're going uphill and lugging it at the same time, your engine might be oil starved, which could flash the CEL when the oil pressure gets low enough. Some cars use the CEL as an oil pressure "idiot light" (Note: I'm not calling you an idiot, it just means it's sort of fool proof). If there's low oil or there's enough wear on the engine, you could be causing the oil pressure to go below the threshold (usually 5psi) which would cause the light to come on.

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing the CEL light?  I've known Volkswagens flash their ignition lights just prior to a stall.